# Principal focus question

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

On my notes İ have written that the definition of principle focus is : the point on the principal axes where rays appear to diverge or rays actually converge.

However İ was looking at this diagram of a concave mirror.

[image]

The rays do not converge at the principal focus .

So is the definition wrong.

As you can see the rays do not converge at point F (principal focus) which is ironical to the definition.

The image is not formed on the principal focus which from the definition is what should happen.
Why is this?

Update.: From the answers given İ understand this now, however İ don't know why lots of websites do not include that it is for parallel rays only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my notes İ have written that the definition of principal focus is : the point on the principal axes where rays appear to diverge or rays actually converge.

should read

On my notes İ have written that the definition of principle focus is : the point on the principal axes where rays **initially parallel to the principal axis** appear to diverge or rays actually converge.

In your diagram ray **1** passes through the focal point.

Also ray **2** does the same in reverse.

Comment: But the rays do not converge at point F.

Comment: The ray which is initially parallel to the principal axis (ray **1**) does pass through $F$. Also if you reverse the direction of travel of the light the same is true of ray**2**.  Your other rays in the diagram are never parallel to the principal axis.

Comment: Buy the image isn't formed at poin t F. Which is where it should from the definition.